# Jest: How to test for optional object keys

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Say, I have an object below

> const obj1 = {name: expect.any(String)}

Backend return response as below with object the key 'age' as optional key

> const response = {name: 'bbb', age: 10}

So, how can I assert obj1 have age as the optional key, which means if it exists, it must be number type, if it doesn't exist, we can omit the checking ?

> expect(response).toMatchObject(obj1);

Comment: we use ajv for json schema validation, which has the required keyword to check mandatory object properties: https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a built-in function for that, but [toMatchObject](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject) along with destructuring can do what you need:

```
expect({
  age: 0, 
  ...response
}).toMatchObject(obj1);
```

If `age` is not present in the object, it will assume 0; if it is present, it will use the present value and therefore fail if it's the wrong type.

Answer (score -4):

From what i can understand, you want to check that if the property is defined, check that its type is a number? And if the property does not exist then do not check the property type? Correct?

Assuming that the above understanding is correct, this should do:

```js
        const response = {name: "bbb", age:10};
        if (response.age) {
            if (typeof response.age === 'number') {
            console.log("age is a number");
            //your logic if age is a number
            }
            else {
            //your logic in case age exists but its not a number
            }
        }
        else {
        //your logic in case age does not exist
        }
```

Comment: This question was specifically about jest, so a good answer would refer to specific jest solutions